# High chance of connection failure due to full wait queue on specific datasets

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

We're using the .NET driver for MongoDB and I got a report recently that a specific project (among 100+) cannot be opened in our app. The error is always a full wait queue while connecting to the primary shard (we have 1 primary and 2 secondary).

The odd thing is that this happens 99% of the time on this specific project while most other projects can be loaded without issues at any time. Randomly the error appeared on other ones as well, but there it's like 2% compared. After a few reloads the project eventually gets loaded, so it's not happening all the time but most of it.

We already increased the pool size to 200 (should be sufficient for our workload). We don't have bursts of requests usually and loading the project is a simple load of the project matching the UUID and returning it. So one of the least complex operations we have (returns the whole document).

We have around 40 connections all the time, sometimes bursting up to 150 at maximum on each shard. It's a M10 cluster so the problem is not server-side (supports up to 1500 connections).

This issue never occured before and workloads haven't increased drastically. Any idea what the issue could be? It's really odd, I'd expect this to happen on all projects alike but it happens more for some than for others. What's also weird is that it fails in about 2 seconds. I think I read that the default connection timeout is 30 seconds.

Any ideas what could cause this? Or how to fix this? It's hard to track down since there are no client-side metrics easily accessible.

**EDIT** as requested the connection settings:

```
mongoDB:
  maxConnectionPoolSize: "400"
  minConnectionPoolSize: "10"
  maxConnecting: "4"
  maxConnectionIdleTime: "300000"
  maxConnectionLifeTime: "1800000"
```

Comment: see https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.18/frequently_encountered_issues/

Comment: also, provide what configuration you set to the client

Comment: The thing is this occurs for specific documents in the database, but not for all. For those it does it happens 99% of the time. After several reloads it sometimes works. For most other documents it works without any issues. The primary shard has 80-150 connections max at all time, the clients (two replicas) have a pool size of 400 (so 2000 wait queue), minimum 4 connections and max idle time of 5 minutes for those connections. Locally I never have more than 8 connections at any point of time. So even if production has latency and multiple users (not a lot atm), it should never reach the

Comment: pool size limit. Especially not the wait queue. So this seems more like a bug than an issue in our application. Also the connection fails instantly although the connection timeout is 30 seconds by default. So how can it be that it fails instantly then?

Comment: 1. As I said, you should provide a full client configuration. 2. A small repro, create a console application that emulates the issue as well as the full error message. 3. ` 30 seconds by default.` - do you mean server selection timeout?

Comment: Added them to the post. 2. Well I can't spend a month now ripping our application apart to isolate the issue and I can't write a small console app that messes with out live databases either. 3. No I mean the "ConnectTimeout" (see here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/csharp/current/fundamentals/connection/connection-options/). The connection fails instantly although there should be plenty of space in the wait queue (and neither operations take that long nor are there a lot of single operations when this isssue occurs)

Comment: 1. It's not full configuration, there is nothing about server configuration like whether you use replica set or no and similar. 2. It's up to you, what you have provided is not enough. Please see the link in my first message about why this issue usually appear. You mention `on this specific project while most other projects can be loaded without issues at any time` - which may mean that something weird happens inside this project (ie in configuration, the way how you use the driver, data and etc). To say something you should provide a code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: 3. if you mean this option `maxConnectionIdleTime: "300000"` - then it's 300 seconds and this value only means that if connection is not used 300 seconds, the driver should consider it stale and recreate it

Comment: `connectTimeoutMS` - is unrelated to this issue, it just specifies how long driver will wait the server response during first handshake for connection

Comment: btw, what happens if you remove `maxConnectionPoolSize: "400"` and the rest of options you specified in the question?

Comment: Modifying the options did not help in any way. Be it removing them or increasing them drastically. Using metrics and outputting the command events that MongoDB generates I could see that we had deep down a very imperformant implicit bottleneck where the database was called hundreds of times. The weird thing remains: Locally it never had more than ~3-8 connections and some projects always worked fine. Anyway I fixed that issue and the problems are gone. Still the behavior makes not much sense. I don't get how the queues could fill up that easily... Thanks for the help though!